# ltablex and booktabs

Tags: booktabs, ltablex

I need a table which is larger than one page and it should have a fixed size. To improve the look, I use booktabs. However, the foot of the table is not nice on all pages, except on the last page. 
[image]
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
left & right\\\toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Is there a possibility to detect, if a row will be the last row on a page? Than I would be able to avoid the double line. Like the following pseudo code

```
is row last row of the page than \bottomrule else \midrule
```

I would like to have only a `\bottomrule` at the end of each page but no double line

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but possibly of some relevance anyway: For your MWE at least (and possibly your real document too), you may want to replace `\toprule` with `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]` since the rule at the top of each page actually has some material above it (as well as below it, of course).

Comment: A pagebreak is only possible _after_ a tabular line and not within a tabular line! So you always have a `\midrule` because you use `\\\midrule` after each tabular row. Replace `\endfoot` with `\endlastfoot` and use only a `\\\` for the last tabular row.

Comment: the problem is, I can not use \\ for the last tabular row on each page, because I do not know, how many rows are there (the tables are generated)

Comment: I realise this is probably a really dumb question but what does `\\* ` do that's different from `\\ `? (It isn't possible to format just two backslashes as code here?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution A)** I am not sure if I am following the question, but you don't need `\bottomrule` at all, it is a simple rule where you can only set a width of it. In my example I am removing it and I am adding one extra rule at the very end of the table.

```
%! *latex mal-ltablex-a.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
left & right\\\toprule
\endhead
%\bottomrule
\endfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule 
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe 1]

**Edit, Solution B)** In case you really need that, I am using this trick as a patch. I am saving information about page number (`\label`) at the end of each row and in next runs of TeX I am deciding if to typeset `\midrule` or `\bottomrule` (I am comparing actual and the following row -- it is a looking ahead situation).

In case you would like to have `\bottomrule` at the very end of your table, please comment out `\mycounting` written on the before the last line.

```
%! *latex mal-ltablex-b.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{refcount}

\let\oldmidrule=\midrule
\newcount\malic 
\global\malic=0
\newcount\maltempa \maltempa=0
\newcount\maltempb \maltempb=0

\def\midrule{%
\mycounting
\ifnum\maltempa=\maltempb
  \\*\oldmidrule
\else
  \\*\bottomrule[6pt]
\fi
}%End of \midrule...

\def\mycounting{%
\global\advance\malic by 2%
\maltempb=\getpagerefnumber{mycounter-\the\malic}%
\global\advance\malic by -1%
\maltempa=\getpagerefnumber{mycounter-\the\malic}%
\typeout{\the\maltempa, \the\maltempb}
\label{mycounter-\the\malic}%
}% End of \mycounting...


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
left & right\\\toprule
\endhead
%\bottomrule
\endfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule 
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule 
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule 
%\blindtext & \blindtext \midrule
\end{tabularx}

\mycounting % Comment out this line in case you would like to have \bottomrule at the very end of the table...
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe 2]

Answer (score 3):

In your example, there seems to be little point -- typographically speaking -- of having both "heavy" rules (generated by `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`) and "light" rules (generated by `\midrule`). I therefore suggest you use only one rule width, say, `\heavyrulewidth`, for *all rules*. Here's how you might implement such a setup:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,ltablex,blindtext}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{\heavyrulewidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
left & right\\ \toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule % use \bottomrule only on final page
\endlastfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Conversely, if you prefer to have all rules have the thickness of `\lightrulewidth`, you'd issue the instruction

```
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{\lightrulewidth}
```

Answer (score 2):

This addresses the issue by moving up vertically a faux `\bottomrule` (the `\raisebox` contents) to overlay any residual `\midrule`, thus avoiding the appearance of a double rule.  There is, however, a side effect: an extra line of vertical space is taken by this manipulation, and so one has one less row to work with per page.  To see this, comment out my `\raisebox` and uncomment the original `\bottomrule` and you will find the "X Y" row move from the top of page 2 to the bottom of page 1.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
left & right\\\toprule
\endhead
\raisebox{9pt}{\smash{\makebox[.972\textwidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}}}%
%\bottomrule
\endfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
X & Y\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\*\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this code (I replaced \endfoot with \endlastfoot) give what you want?

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}%
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{ltablex}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    left & right\\\toprule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    \blindtext & \blindtext\\\midrule
    \blindtext & \blindtext\\\midrule
    \blindtext & \blindtext\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, I'm interested to have one bottomrule at the end of each page but no double line (midrule and bottomrule)

Comment: @Micha: I modified my answer. Is that OK now?

Comment: no, I've edited the first question to see, what I'm looking for

Comment: @Micha: Pardon me, but _what_ is the difference between you second image and what I've produced? I surely do miss something.

Comment: the last line on page one is `\midrule`, not `\bottomrule` (I need the footer)

Comment: @Micha; Oh! I see. I thought what bothered you was the double line at the end of first page. So, just to be sure, you want a `\bottomline` at the end of each  intermediate page ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have only a `\bottomrule` at the end of each page but no double line

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex,tabu}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
left & right\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{continues next page} \\*\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext\\\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\\midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this problem, you ask two problems

**Problem 1:** How to make an long table with every page ends with `\bottomrule`.

It is easier to solve, just delete the second `\middlerule`.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    left & right\\ \toprule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
\blindtext & \blindtext\\ \midrule
\blindtext & \blindtext\\ 
\blindtext & \blindtext\\
\end{tabularx}
```

And results are shown below:
[image]

**Problem 2:** You want the code having the ability to determine whether the page is end with that ''row''.

As I known, the *end of table* and *end of row* are implemented in different ways.
The headline and footline are defined at the begin of the table,

```
left & right\\ \toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
```

but the middleline are defined after each row.

```
\blindtext & \blindtext\\ \midrule
```

I have no ability to determine the appearance of `\middlerule` or not, unless they are defined in same way. Generally we use ''spacing'' instead of lines.